# Self-destructing class containing a window

Tags: c++, winapi

I've created a print preview class, PPREVIEW, containing a print preview window, which is supposed to popup over my app's main window, while disabling it. When user closes preview window, it is supposed to enable main window and destroy PPREVIEW object. I'd like to use it in the following way:

```
PPREVIEW *p=new PPREVIEW;
//next, preview window is created, user interaction begins
p->ShowPreview(<parameters>); //but this function returns
delete p;
```

Since ShowPreview does return, the above line would destroy object while window is still visible. If it was a modal dialog box, this would be possible, since DialogBox function doesn't return at that point.
I thought i could put "delete this" somewhere upon destruction of the print preview window. Naturally WM_DESTROY comes to mind. But MSDN states at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632620%28v=vs.85%29.aspx the following: "it can be assumed that during processing of WM_DESTROY child windows still exist", so there's still possibility some of them will refer to instance's variables (and they do, i was getting random access violation errors when i tried that, so i backed out).

Currently i've opted to:
- create some global variable,
- in WM_DESTROY of print preview window i put EnableWindow(MainWindow, TRUE) and set that global variable to FALSE.
- Then, upon main window's WM_ENABLE event i'm testing global variable for FALSE and deleting object.

But this is quite unelegant and requires that i program this behavior for every window that uses print preview, so i decided to pursue previous approach, which is: create, use, possibly self-delete. I need either:
- information when exactly could i use "delete this" in PPREVIEW window procedure, if this approach isn't unwise for some reason i am unaware of
- an idea how to make ShowPreview method to not return, mimicking DialogBox behavior.
- other suggestions that achieve my goal

Please assist.

Comment: Why does ShowPreview return if the window is modal? Also, don't use `new` here, it's not needed at all.

Comment: I should clarify: window ISN'T modal, it is created by CreateWindowEx, i only mentioned DialogBox function since i'd like my window to behave that way too.

Comment: @Kitet: `DialogBox` doesn't return simply because it is modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your `ShowPreview` function should call `ShowWindow()` to show the preview window. It should also do whatever is needed to the main form, e.g. disabling it.
2. When your preview window receives `WM_CLOSE` it should delete the C++ object that wraps it. Some part of this process also needs to call `DestroyWindow()` on the underlying window handle. The default handling of `WM_CLOSE` would do this, but perhaps you would want this in the C++ object's destructor.

Comment: Actually, i wanted either self-destructing class or modal window. Since i was closer to Your answer, i tried that instead trying alternate message loop, and it works. Will test for few days though, before accepting answer. Last time i put "delete this" in WM_DESTROY it that caused random problems. For now, i think i'm set.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `ShowPreview` to be modal, you'll need to run a sub-message-loop. You can find [some examples here](http://www.mvps.org/user32/modal.html), including a reverse-engineered version of what `DialogBox` uses internally.

Alternately, you can simply have the `WM_DESTROY` of the preview window both re-enable the main window and delete your `PPREVIEW *` (in which case `ShowPreview` won't be modal, but it will be self-contained). You have to be careful here not to touch the `PPREVIEW *` (or, from within `PPREVIEW`'s member functions, not to call any other members or access any member variables) after the `DestroyWindow()` call though - this in particular means you cannot access member variables in your message handler after the `DefWindowProc()` call

Comment: Will try the sub-message loop now. The WM_DESTROY thing - i did that at first and had many access violations long after closing preview window, as i wrote above. Took me hours to trace them back to this.

Comment: @Kitet Sub-message loop is what you do for modal windows. But you said you want a modeless window which should be run from the main message loop. Do you want a modal window or not? I'm now unsure.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The loop shown by bdonlan, although modal in some sense, does not cause modal behavior from either child or parent window.  A dialog's modal message loop processes messages for windows outside its containment tree without calling the window procedure.

Comment: @BenVoigt, how does one process messages without calling window procedures, exactly?

Comment: @bdonlan: Well, you might handle mousemove by setting a wait cursor, mouse clicks by beeping, and throw away the rest.

Comment: @BenVoigt, Throwing away messages permanently sounds like a really dangerous idea to me :) I mean, a blacklist would be reasonable, I guess - but doesn't disabling the window do all that for you?

Comment: @bdonlan: Does `EnableWindow` interact with message processing, or is it up to the recipient to notice that it's been disabled and ignore the message?  Of course, making enable/disable work right is a good idea regardless.

Comment: @BenVoigt, not sure really - pretty sure it does though :)

Comment: @bdonlan: Anyway, I remembered that there is something special about a dialog modal loop... it's the call to `IsDialogMessage`, which your loop is missing.

Comment: @BenVoigt, isn't that only needed for true dialog boxes, though - not pseudo-dialogs which are really modal normal windows?